# How can I apply style based on a trigger property to a content control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the current WPF application that I am working on, I have to invert the color of an icon when the mouse is pressed on (when property isPressed=true ). The reason why I need to do is I want to keep the consistency of the application with regard to the icon color and background. But this icon is embedded within a button which when clicked displays a similar color and hence the icon is not visible

As my style trigger picks up the red color that I have set but the color of the geometry is not changed. Is there any way I can use this style trigger to set the color of the geometry also to Red when (isPressed=true)?

Here is my code

My Style is as follows

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="yellow" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I tried setting a setter property to content as yellow just to see if it works but it did not work

The part where it is being used is as follows

```
<Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ContentBackground}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
            <Button
                x:Name="NameButton" 

                Style="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}"
                >


                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="Icon"
                                        Width="25"
                                        Height="25"
                                        ">

                        </ContentControl>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                "/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>

            </Button>
        </Border>
```

As shown in the images as well the style is picked up by the textblock but I do not know how I can add this style to the contentcontrol which has the icons

**Edit** :- Example of icon specified in the application

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FolderIcon">
        <Path 
              Fill="#047F89"
              Data="....."/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What kind of icon is this, a xaml? If so you have to bind the `Fill` of the `Path` or `Geometry` to the first ancestor's `Contol.Foreground` (or `Button.Foreground`) instead of setting it directly. Now the icon color will adapt to the current `Foreground`.

Comment: BioniCode Thank you for the comment .. I have edited the question with the type of icons I have ... can you kindly assist me with what needs to be done

Comment: Ok, I will give you an example. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind the `Fill` property of the `Path` to the parent `Control` element's `Control.Foreground` (or `Button.Foreground`) instead of setting it directly. Now the icon color will adapt to the `Foreground` value assigned by the trigger. I also removed the redundant `Grid` of the `Button.Content` and the `Content` `Setter` of the `Trigger` as it would remove the icon `Path` element every time the `Button` is pressed and added the default `Forground` value to the Style (moved from `Path.Fill` to Style-Setter):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#047F89" />

  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
     </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Button x:Name="NameButton"        
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}">
  <Button.Content>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Control}, Path=Foreground}"
            Height="16"
            Width="16"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="5,0,0,0"
            Data="....."/>

      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                 TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
    <StackPanel>
  <Button.Content>
</Button>
```

The `Binding` on `Path.Fill` would still work in case you decide to move the `Path` to a `ResourceDictionary`.